# SQL to return records NOT IN sub query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to return all records that are not in

```
Select UID FROM EnrollmentsTbl WHERE (UID Is Not Null)
```

The current SQL statement returns all records in linked tables `UsersDataTbl` and `UsersDataCareerTbl`

From what I have researched, using an indexed field `UID` will not produce the results I want, when I use another field like `UserName` the desired results are rendered:

Is there a work-around to allow me to use indexed field in a sub query?

The following returns all records from the linked tables but does not exclude sub query records:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 

     DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT UsersDataTbl.StudentID, 
                           UsersDataTbl.LastName, UsersDataTbl.FirstName, 
                           UsersDataTbl.UID, UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion, 
                           UsersDataCareerTbl.Station, UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift
                     FROM UsersDataTbl 
                     LEFT JOIN UsersDataCareerTbl ON UsersDataTbl.UID = UsersDataCareerTbl.UID
                     WHERE (((UsersDataTbl.Career) = True) 
                       AND ((UsersDataTbl.Active) = True) 
                       AND ((UsersDataTbl.UID) NOT IN 
                            (SELECT UID FROM EnrollmentsTbl 
                             WHERE (UID IS NOT NULL)))) 
                     ORDER BY UsersDataTbl.LastName, UsersDataTbl.FirstName">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

The following returns the desired results (but UserName is not a desired or reliable field):

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT UsersDataTbl.StudentID, UsersDataTbl.LastName, UsersDataTbl.FirstName, 
UsersDataTbl.UID, UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion, UsersDataCareerTbl.Station, UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift
FROM UsersDataTbl LEFT JOIN UsersDataCareerTbl ON UsersDataTbl.UID = UsersDataCareerTbl.UID
WHERE (((UsersDataTbl.Career)=True) AND ((UsersDataTbl.Active)=True) AND ((UsersDataTbl.UID) 
Not In (Select UserName FROM EnrollmentsTbl WHERE (UserName Is Not Null)))) 
ORDER BY UsersDataTbl.LastName, UsersDataTbl.FirstName">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: I feel like you should have more than just an "ms-access' tag on your question.

Comment: `From what I have researched, using an indexed field UID will not produce the results I want, when I use another field like UserName the desired results are rendered:` Can you clarify?

Comment: it is solely an access SQL question - that being said, I'm having more people editing and correcting my question than actually looking at the issue - very frustrating for a novelist looking for help!

Comment: the UID is used to link the tables, when used in the sub query it doesn't return limited records - if I use another field i.e. UserName than it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could left join EnrollmentsTbl to UsersDataTbl on UID, then add `And EnrollmentsTbl.UID Is Null` to your WHERE clause.

Alternatively, you could use a NOT EXISTS clause, though I'd expect poorer performance from an Access db:

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM EnrollmentsTbl et WHERE et.UID = UsersDataTbl.UID)
```

Comment: turns out my UID record was not NULL it contained a 0. - changed to: `And (EnrollmentsTbl.UID Is Null OR EnrollmentsTbl.UID < 1)`